# How do I insert a new column with Python's xlsxwriter at the beginning of an excelb table

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

How do I insert a new column with Python's xlsxwriter at the beginning of an excel table.I inserted the excel target encountered a problem: how to insert a new table at the beginning of a sheet, do not know xlsxwriter have this function, trouble you help solve this problem

Comment: Could you please post what you've tried already? People on Stack Overflow are willing to help you, but not to do your work for you. Show us what you've attempted and any errors that you are receiving.

Comment: Thank you for hinting, for example: I insert a data in the A column (the first column) 1 row of cells, worksheet.write ('A1', 'Hello'), and now I need to insert a cell before A1

Answer (score 1):

Hi Please try,

```
    workbook   = xlsxwriter.Workbook('filename.xlsx')

    worksheet1 = workbook.add_worksheet()
    worksheet2 = workbook.add_worksheet()

    worksheet1.write('A1', 123)

    workbook.close()
```

Here Column is specified as A1 and value 123.

```
# These are equivalent.
worksheet.write(0, 0, 'Hello')
worksheet.write('A1', 'Hello')
```

To insert a new column at specified position use :

```
def insert_column(self):

  # Instantiating a Workbook object by excel file path
  workbook = self.Workbook(self.dataDir + 'Book1.xls')

  # Accessing the first worksheet in the Excel file
  worksheet = workbook.getWorksheets().get(0)

  # Inserting a column into the worksheet at 2nd position
  worksheet.getCells().insertColumns(1,1)

  # Saving the modified Excel file in default (that is Excel 2003) format
  workbook.save(self.dataDir + "Insert Column.xls")

  print "Insert Column Successfully."
```

Comment: Worksheet.write ('A1', 'Hello') or worksheet.write (0, 0, 'Hello'), this is just insert data in A1, but the result I want is to replace A1 with a new cell But the contents of the A1 will be moved back, that is to say in the A1 before inserting a cell

Comment: I do not want to create a method to achieve this function, do not know xlsxwriter there is no similar way to achieve this function

Comment: To write a column use
data = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [2, 4, 6, 8, 10],
    [3, 6, 9, 12, 15],
]

worksheet.write_column('A1', data[0]) @MrFiona

Comment: But the contents of the A1 cell are covered instead of being moved

Comment: If so before operations swap datas using these functions

Comment: If xlsxwriter no similar function can only do so, I move more data, may lead to lower efficiency

Comment: Fine then wait for better answers, I only gave you the basics as I know. Thanks